# How to customize pagination by hiding numbers

Tags: backbone.js, bootstrap-table

I want to customize the bootstrap-table pagination by hiding numbers and show next, previous,first and last like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TScP2.png)

I want to customize the bootstrap-table pagination by hiding numbers and show next, previous,first and last buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery or Js by hiding the numbers and keep the text

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide the page numbers
  $('.pagination').find('li').not('.prev,.next,.first,.last').hide();
  // Update the button text
  $('.pagination').find('.prev').html('&laquo; Previous');
  $('.pagination').find('.next').html('Next &raquo;');
  $('.pagination').find('.first').html('First');
  $('.pagination').find('.last').html('Last');
});
```

We hide all list items (li) except the ones with classes .prev, .next, .first, and .last. Then, we update the HTML content of these buttons to display the desired text

```
 <table id="myTable" data-pagination="true" data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 
   100]" data-show-pagination-switch="true">
<!-- Your table content here -->
</table>
```

You can replace  with your actual table content.
Remember to include the necessary CSS and JS dependencies for Bootstrap and jQuery in your project.

Comment: Is there any option in bootstrap-table itself or do I need to extend and write the custom logic?

Comment: According to my knowledge as you described to achieve that you have to write custom logic :)